# Override all default resources / responses from Twisted.web

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

For a super-basic http twisted front-end.
How can I make sure no html is ever written back unless I tell it to.

So, I have my /zoo url below.
For any tracebacks, or 'No Such Resource' responses, I want to just drop the connection or return an empty response.

I guess it's a super-simple one but can't figure it out :)
I know I could do it byt not having my specific Child path, but want to do it efficient, would just want to drop it as early as possible.. Maybe not use Resource?

```
class HttpApi(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_POST(self, request):
        return "post..."


application = service.Application("serv")

json_api = resource.Resource()
json_api.putChild("zoo", HttpApi())
web_site = server.Site(json_api)
internet.TCPServer(8001, web_site).setServiceParent(application)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some basics first

The way twisted.web works is

There is class called [Site](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html) which is a HTTP factory. 
This is called for every request. In fact, a function called getResourceFor is called to obtain the appropriate resource that will serve this request. 
This Site class is initialized with root resource. And the function Site.getResourceFor calls [resource.getChildForRequest](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html#getResourceFor) on the root resource

Call flow is:

> Site.getResourceFor -> resource.getChildForRequest (root resource)

Now it is time to look at getChildForRequest:

```
def getChildForRequest(resource, request):
    """
    Traverse resource tree to find who will handle the request.
    """
    while request.postpath and not resource.isLeaf:
        pathElement = request.postpath.pop(0)
        request.prepath.append(pathElement)
        resource = resource.getChildWithDefault(pathElement, request)
    return resource
```

What happens is as resources are registered with putChild(path), they become child resources of that resource.
An example:

```
root_resource
|
|------------ resource r1 (path = 'help')
|----resource r2 (path = 'login')  |
|                                  |----- resource r3 (path = 'registeration')
|                                  |----- resource r4 (path = 'deregistration')
```

Some reflections:

1. Now r1 will server request with path http://../help/
2. Now r3 will server request with path http://../help/registration/
3. Now r4 will server request with path http://../help/deregistration/

But

1. r3 will server request with path http://../help/registration/xxx/
2. r3 will server request with path http://../help/registration/yyy/

> For the solution:

You will need to subclass Site to

1. check if the path excatly matches the resource returned with pathElement empty and only then process it or
2. return a resource which will be your handler to handle other aspects

You will have to create your own resource

```
def render(self, request):
    request.setResponseCode(...)
    return ""
```